# Overriding or blocking validation errors in django rest api

Tags: django, rest, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to override or block validation error in django rest framework. If  for example i have the following code

```
class Function(models.Model):



name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

I need some kind of way to block the unique=True for name. How to handle that in serializer?

```
class FunctionSerializerWithOnlyName(serializers.ModelSerializer):

def validate_name(self, value):
        # it is always returning name needs to be unique even if i raise another error
        return value


class Meta:
    model = Function
    fields = ( 'name',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fastest way was to change FunctionSerializerWithOnlyName to serializers.Serializer and unlink it from the Function object.

```
class FunctionSerializerWithOnlyName(serializers.Serializer):

name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)

def validate_name(self, value):
    try:
        function = Function.objects.get(name=value)
    except:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("The function name '"+value+"' is not available")
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

`unique` is enforced on db level.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#unique

..so it's not possible. You need to remove unique from model field and check for uniqueness inside the code.

Comment: DRF also enforces this manually with their validators, so it is possible to get around that (by removing them).

Comment: @KevinBrown Hmm.. wouldn't you get db level exception even after you remove the validators?

Comment: Yup, but my guess is that they are working around that somehow. They did mention getting validation errors instead of integrity errors...

Comment: @mariodev I am doing a GET here. Something like get function by name so i don't need that kind of validation. is there a way to block validation through GET call?

Comment: @user1200279 GET shouldn't be doing validation at all.

Comment: @KevinBrown i meant I have another model. whenever this model gets POSTED. I do a check for the function(function here is connected to that model as a forgein key) if it is already saved in the database